# Disable root auto login in GNURoot Debian

Tags: vnc

I don't want to work with root account in GNURoot Debian.
I know to change the user from root to user1 by:

> su - user1

However, I still want to disable root auto login; besides, I want to use build-in vncviewer or an extra vncviewer to connect the GNURoot Debian with normal user user1 NOT root, I have no idea to how to config this?